# JavaScript match() function does not give output

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript code I use regular expression match() function to find pattern and show the result, but it does not give a proper answer, means finding [i] character in giving sentences

```
<button onclick = "searchPattern()">pattern</button><br>
<p id = "demo"></p>

<script>
  function searchPattern(){
    var str = "Visti W3Schools!";
    var paat = /[i]/g;
    var result = str.match(patt);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
  }


</script>
```

Comment: Rolled back to original version with the `paat` typo as others suggest it might be the problem

Comment: Fix the typo and you get output. It is the problem.

Comment: This question should be flag as typographic error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your JavaScript console

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: patt is not defined
> ```

You changed your variable name from `paat` to `patt` half way through your code.